# iPhone: App for Web Address recognition

Tags: iphone

When I'm browsing a website on my laptop, I'd like to capture my laptop's screen with the iPhone's camera and be redirected automatically to the corresponding page.

Can you recommend an app that automatically can recognize a URL in a picture?

Comment: Please try a little harder to extend and improve your explanation (and your English) so we can help you

Comment: Why don't you just bookmark it and sync your bookmarks with iCloud? It will be available on the iPhone almost instantly. You can search the App Store for OCR apps, though for this example it hardly makes sense.

Comment: Because my laptop is the PC one. I believe it doesn't have access to iCloud (please, correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 1):

[Handoff](http://www.handoffapp.com/) is a good solution for this. It has a bookmarklet that you use in Safari to send the current web site to the iPhone app.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I'm using PC and Windows 7 without Safari browser installed. oh, I see it does have Chrome extension. I'll try that one..